# I get InvalidOperationException when I try to get posts using LINQ in my ASP .NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I don't know why I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The model backing the 'GuestbookContext'
>   context has changed since the database was created. Consider using
>   Code First Migrations to update the database

After migration, nothing has changed.
But if you remove the attributes [Required], **Index** action works without error.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GuestbookEntries] (
    [Id]       INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] NCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
    [PostText] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [PostDate] DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

My models:

```
namespace Guestbook.Models
{
    public class GuestbookEntry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PostText { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Guestbook.Models
{
    public class GuestbookContext : DbContext
    {
        public GuestbookContext() : base("Guestbook") {} // define name of database
        public DbSet<GuestbookEntry> Entries { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

My GuestbookController:

```
namespace Guestbook.Controllers
{
    public class GuestbookController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Guestbook/
        // 
        private GuestbookContext _db = new GuestbookContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // error here
            var mostRecentEntries = (from entry in _db.Entries orderby entry.PostDate descending select entry).Take(20);
            ViewBag.Entries = mostRecentEntries.ToList();
            return View();
        }
}
```

Comment: The error message says that the model and the database do not match. Can you try updating the db?

Comment: I did the migration of the database, but it did not help.

Comment: Is deleting the database an option in this case?